# Check checkboxes using the contextmenu in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a datagrid (which is filled from the code-behind) with a context menu.

I'd like to check the checkboxes of the selected items (rows) from the context menu using data bindings (maybe with the < MenuItem>'s Command attribute?), but I can't figure out how.

Is this possible?

```
    <DataGrid Name="dgFoo" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Set checked" Icon="{Binding ??? }" />
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Item 2"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dgCheckBoxColumn" Header="Checked?" Binding="{Binding Chckd}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" Binding="{Binding Company}"  IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Next Meeting" Binding="{Binding NextMeeting}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Loc}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: the usual question here is: where are you stuck and can you show the code you have now so we could help you find a solution? (edit your question)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've added some code.

Answer (score 0):

The DataContext for a Context Menu will be the same DataContext as the DataGrid. So, in your VM:

1. Create whatever form of Command you are using in your project. I use DelegateCommand from Prism.
2. Create your command in the constructor and point it at a method in your VM which does the work.
3. Bind your view to the Command.
4. In your method, iterate over "selected rows", toggling the "checked" property in each row.

The annoying thing is that DataGrid doesn't allow you to bind SelectedItems to a collection. So you need to either add some small code-behind to handle the SelectionChanged event and populate that list yourself in your VM, or you use a style to bind the IsSelected property of the DataGridRow to a property on your VM items. Then you can work out which items are selected.

As the other user suggested - with code we can help you more.

Comment: Thank you, I find this useful. The code is very generic, nevertheless  I'll add it soon.